# Missing fonts when previewing Next.js app in Experience Editor

Tags: jss, experience-editor, nextjs

I've got a Next.js-based app that uses custom fonts. On the Rendering host the fonts are accessible via the following url:

```
https://www.myapp.localhost/_next/static/media/lato-latin-400-normal.b7ffde23.woff2
```

Experience Editor tries to load fonts from CM but the fonts are not found and 404 is returned:

```
https://cm.localhost/_next/static/media/lato-latin-400-normal.b7ffde23.woff2
```

In the same time, the `webpack.js` file is requested from the Rendering host and successfully received:

```
https://www.myapp.localhost/_next/static/chunks/webpack.js?ts=1665501553546
```

How to make Experience Editor request fonts from the Rendering host?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tell your NextJS app to render the fonts using absolute URL.

We did it in our app by setting the PUBLIC_URL variable to the base URL of our app, which in your case, https://www.myapp.localhost.

You will also need to configure your NextJS app to allow cross domain request from your CM hostname. See [this doc](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/headers) to see how you can modify http headers in NextJS.

Comment: Thanks @chenz. The PUBLIC_URL was already set in my case. The absolute urls appear when rendering container starts with command `start:production` (insted of `start:connected` used for development).

Comment: Currently I'm struggling with CORS configuration. Using this example: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/33318#issuecomment-1014434541

It works only if I use "*" as origin. If I put CM url there, the rendering container does not start...

Comment: Ok, found this in CORS error: `access-control-allow-origin: http://cd`. Looks like the rendering expects requests from CD only (I used CD as API host). But that is another issue to solve.

Comment: https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/33251/allow-cors-request-from-cm-to-rendering-host