# Allow CORS request from CM to Rendering host

Tags: jss, experience-editor, nextjs, jss-rendering-sdk, rendering-host

Related to [Missing fonts when previewing Next.js app in Experience Editor](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/33191/missing-fonts-when-previewing-next-js-app-in-experience-editor).

I've got the Rendering container with `SITECORE_API_HOST` set to CD. In CM Experience Editor I see some CORS errors caused by Rendering. In order to let CM access Rendering, the following configuration is added to the `next.config.js`:

```
async headers() {
  return [
    {
      source: '/_next/static/media/:path*',
      headers: [{ key: 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin', value: '*' }],
    },
  ];
}
```

This works but to make it more secure I'd like instead of "*" set the CM url. Doing that leads to `The operation has timed out` error... Rendering works fine.

What is missing here? Is it safe to leave "*" for the static files?

Answer (score 1):

Solved adding `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` header:

```
async headers() {
  return [
    {
      source: '/_next/static/media/:path*',
      headers: [
        { key: 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin', value: 'https://cm.myapp.localhost' },
        { key: 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods', value: 'GET,OPTIONS' },
      ],
    },
  ];
},
```